# Plagiarism flag declined by mod. The other answer copied part of code and added "It works for me" only

Tags: support, declined-flags

In a question, I answered some days ago with a full working code and explaining some details.

In the next day, another person copied the important part from my code and added the caption **Try this It works for me**. So, it is a plagiarism. I flagged it for mod yesterday but mod rejected it.

**Part of My answer**

[image]

**The Other answer**

[image]

Probably this should be a comment. So, I flagged it as NAA. but declined.

Then I flagged it for mod as Plagiarism and It also got declined.

[image]

Comment: if they did copied and pasted your code they went further by deleting one line and adding a space for the second CSS rule. though still a crap answer in my oppinion

Comment: Given your criteria for plagiarism I accuse you both of plagiarising [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35517611/1038015). Alternatively perhaps you could consider the code fragment is too trivial/obvious to support any plagiarism accusation.

Comment: `.draggable` is pretty generic - I use it as a selector too

Comment: Is it a matter for declining plagiarism?

Comment: I'd argue yes, the flag was rightly declined. I agree it sucks seeing the same code presented by someone else as a new thing - the answer totally deserves downvoting - but the case for plagiarism is a bit thin.

Comment: @RobertLongson I spend almost half an hour working on the issue, tried hover, tried changing cursor for body, etc and at last I reached :active.

Comment: So what, the amount of time you spent is not relevant here.

Comment: @RobertLongson agree but one spend much time and made an answer. another one just copied it and removed 1 line and make it as answer. then what should I do.

Comment: I'm saying you have no proof of that given that the code is a) similar rather than identical and b) trivial/obvious You should take a break and move on, there's nothing else to do here.

Comment: @Pekka웃 the same thing I found many times but the time diff is just seconds or 1 or 2 minutes. In such case, it is not a plagiarism. Both were making answer. I too faced such situation. When we type a complete answer and post it, then I saw the same answer posted by another user seconds before. But here is a one day gap.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible they copied it from you. It's still not unique enough to be plagiarism. German Copyright law has a nice term for that, *Schöpfungshöhe*, literally "height of creation". It's a bar in originality and complexity that your work needs to pass so a copy/reuse of it can be considered plagiarism. A bit of fairly generic code doesn't pass that bar. Just downvote it because it's a bad answer.

Comment: Did someone flagged this as NAA? Is basically a "thanks" answer.

Comment: @Braiam No, it's *not*.  It's not thanking someone else for anything, it's presenting an answer.

Comment: Looking at that user's answer history, I don't see any attempt at plagiarizing, so I'd assume good faith that it's really his own attempt at answering. *Similar CSS rule can't be avoided since the question has `.dragable` already*. In the end, he acknowledged that his answer didn't work, so what's the issue?

Answer (score 21):

For a plagiarism flag to be successful there needs to be substantial evidence that there is indeed a non-original re-work (or an obvious 1-on-1 copy) of an answer that it can't be an simple accident.

I have two problems with what you claim to be plagiarized:

1. the tiny bit of code in the other answer is different: it misses a single line and it has a different spacing in `.draggable:active {` notice the space in front of the { that is missing in your code. And as there is not much more to go on, the mod rightfully err'd on the safe side and declined your flag.
2. True plagiarists are not stupid. The biggest cases copy answers and code from all over the place and post them as their own. Their game is to gain rep without being detected. Posting plagiarized stuff in the same Q/A pair is just defeating both goals. It is unlikely, although enough cases exist, that a true major plagiarism attempt is done on the same Q/A pair.

Keep in mind that plagiarism is a severe breach of the user agreement and flags for those cases shouldn't be raised lightheartedly, specially if there little to no concrete evidence they actually did copy/paste (close to 100% verbatim).
Now if you really do feel there is something suspicious going on that might become apparent if a moderator takes a deeper look into the post and the user, then by all means raise a flag. Keep in mind though that in the end, there might simply not be enough evidence to make a clear call, leading to a declined flag.
I have had plagiarism flags declined when going over a user profile where 80% of their posts where copy/paste. That was for posts with only a few lines of code or text. Despite the user being a plagiarist, despite the few lines turning up in other answers or the internet, that few lines was not enough evidence for the mod to mark my flag helpful for that specific post.

Let me share on observation with you: Evil minds could think that you're only flagging those answers, once as NAA and then with a custom flag and now posting on Meta only to get rid of the competing answers. It might not be your intent but it has that smell.

**tl;dr;**
Always assume good faith, raise custom flags to report plagiarism only on blatantly clear cases (with enough evidence) or when you found a pattern. Include the link(s) to where it is copied from and whether or not proper attribution is provided.

Answer (score 9):

Given the nature of your complain and facts presented, the moderator(s) who declined your flags were absolutely right.

I must admit I share the feeling such an answer (virtually same as a previous one, without any concrete alternative) is not of great quality, but there's nothing much you can do here.

Talking about plagiarism in this instance I may say is out of place for reasons already cited in comments; it's quite negligible.

You may downvote if necessary, citing your reasons, but as it stands, I think your emotions carries it rather than objectiveness and as such, not "so justifiable" in my humble opinion.

I advice you simply forget about this experience, learn from it and move ahead.